# Python interactive mode history and arrow keys

Tags: python, macos

I was wondering if anyone can explain why all of a sudden in Python interactive mode all arrow keys are failing?

When I press up button for example to go through command history I get "^[[A". Same with any other arrow keys.

I have no idea why this happened and it was working before (on OS X Snow Leopard). Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Many thanks,

G

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't say which Python you are using but the symptoms you mention are indeed usually caused by Python not being built with `readline` support.  These days Python on OS X can be built to use either the GNU `readline` library or the Apple-supplied `editline` library (AKA `libedit`).  You can use the following two commands to show exactly which Python you are using.  If that does not help you figure out what is going on, edit your question to show the output from those commands.

Here's an example that shows a recent MacPorts Python 2.6 on OS X 10.6:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print(sys.version);print(sys.executable)'
2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jul 15 2010, 01:53:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)]
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

$ otool -L $(python -c 'import readline; print(readline.__file__)')
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/readline.so:
    /opt/local/lib/libreadline.6.1.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
```

The path prefix `/opt/local/` is the default location for MacPorts-installed software and the output from `otool` indicates that this Python's `readline` module is dynamically linked to the MacPorts-installed GNU `readline` library.

Comment: The hint to look at the Python readline module was helpful. Apparently mine was in fact *not* linked to `libreadline`. I don't know why not, though since readline was installed just fine. Anyway, `port -f uninstall py27-readline; port install py27-readline` fixed it.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using homebrew, this is an easy fix:

```
brew uninstall python
brew uninstall readline
brew install readline  --universal
brew install python
```

That fixed it for me (running OS X Mavericks 10.9.5)

Comment: I just got readline working in python3 for OSX 10.10.1. I had to change the last line to `brew install python --readline --framework` and then I had to do the following: (1) Add `/usr/local/share/python` to my PATH. (2) `pip3.4 install readline`. Then I typed `python3` and readline was working again.

Comment: is this going to replace system Python 2.7.10 with some other version of Python 2.7?

Comment: @user5359531 system python won't be replaced, but if you've already `brew install python` then you follow this procedure, brew may replace _its_ version with a newer one. Check: `which python`, (reports brew's version is at /usr/local/bin/python), `brew unlink python && which python` reports system  version, `brew link python` to reinstate the brew version.  It's non destructive.

Comment: Worked for me too. I am on OS X 10.12

Answer (score 13):

I finally got this working. I just had to install readline with easy_install and cursors and backspace started magically working.

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.5 readline
```

Comment: ``apt-get install libncurses5-dev && pip install readline`` variant worked on my ubuntu (base on trusty)

Comment: `sudo easy_install readline` is what most people need to write

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour commonly shows when you do not have `readline` support. If you are using MacPorts, try `port install readline`, see if it will fix it. You can also see [this page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline/) for some further explanations.

(Also useful to know: some programs do not use `readline` even if present on the system. You can force it on them by using `rlwrap` (`port install rlwrap`). For example: `rlwrap ocaml -init code.ml` will start up OCaml, read code.ml, and start REPL with readline support)

Comment: tried installing readline but it didn't help. Thanks anyway. Will keep digging.

Comment: It worked for me as well. To get it to work with python's pdb, install rlwrap (`port install rlwrap`), then launch python with the command `rlwrap python`. See the man pages for rlwrap for passing arguments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The command

`brew install readline`

worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30028348)