# Python debugger (pdb) stopped handlying up/down arrows, shows ^[[A instead

Tags: python, keyboard, readline, pdb

I am using python 2.6 in a virtualenv on an Ubuntu Linux 11.04 (natty) machine. I have this code in my (django) python code:

```
import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()
```

in order to launch the python debugger (pdb).

Up until today, this worked fine. But now when the pdb starts, it works for debugging and running and breakpoints etc, but when I press the <kbd>up arrow</kbd> to show the previous command it prints `^[[A` instead an doesn't go up. When I type something and press <kbd>Home</kbd>, it prints `^[OH` instead of moving the cursor.

I can use up/home/etc. fine in the bash terminal which launches my python django unittests (which has the pdb call).

What's going on? How do I fix my pdb? What's wrong with my readline?

Comment: @reos Yes, that was a typo. fixed now. it was ``…set_trace()`` in my code

Comment: did you try resetting your shell? `reset`

Comment: What if you "import readline" first? I'm not sure if this is really necessary, but can't hurt to try it.

Comment: Does the up arrow work in the Python interactive shell?

Comment: And can you try "import readline" from the PDB prompt?

Comment: @Rory, could you pls share how you solve it?

Comment: FYI, I have the same problem but the cause of the debugger having trouble is that I set sys.stdout to Unbuffered so long running python apps I run with systemd actually log to journald. This causes the debugger to not work properly. I don't have a fix for it yet, other than rewriting all my print statements to call an unbuffered version of sys.stdout.

Comment: I dont understand what the answers have to do with the question. It suddenly stopped working. Same in my case. Why suddenly?

Answer (score 22):

I found this problem exists when outputting to both console and file using `python file.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt`:

[How to redirect stdout to both file and console with scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906764/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-both-file-and-console-with-scripting)

After removing `2>&1 | tee output.txt`, this problem (up arrow becomes `^[[A` in pdb) disappear.

Comment: Thx. Never expected this occurred the issue.

Comment: Answers like these are why i love SO. I would have guessed that `2>&1 | tee` was related but it was my issue as well

Comment: In a similar manner, I'm debugging a library that implements a logger class and only experience the OP's issue after it executes the line `sys.stdout = self`

Answer (score 21):

Looks like from some reason you are missing the readline package.
Simply install it by typing `pip install readline` and it should behave as expected. Remember to type it as superuser if you're not in venv.

Comment: It seems that the [_readline_](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline) package is deprecated. It has been renamed to [_gnureadline_](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gnureadline) to resolve a name clash with the standard library module.

Comment: The current latest version of readline (6.2.4.1) is broken; it fails to pip install because the C code is invalid. Installing gnureadline produces no difference.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

See [Python interactive mode history and arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483723/python-interactive-mode-history-and-arrow-keys). In my case, Amadan's answer worked; I already had the readline module.