# Output to command line and write to file in python script

Tags: python

I have a python script that currently outputs a bunch of text to stdout (the terminal).  It looks something like:

```
print "ABC"
print "CD"
print "QR"
methodCallToOtherCodeThatAlsoPrints()
# A bunch of other print lines...
```

Right now all of this output just goes to stdout; however, I want the output to be written to a file *in addition* to writing to the terminal.  What is the best way to do this? Ideally I don't want to have to change all of the print statements (to another method call for instance), and I don't have access to some of the code is called to do the printing.

I was thinking, is there someway I can redirect print output to both stdout AND a file?

Comment: This question looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906764/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-file-and-console-with-scripting. There is an answer from Amith Koujalgi that looks like it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

open a file and write your string in it:

```
 with open('my_file' , 'w') as f:
     f.write('your_string')
```

and if you want to redirect your output to a file use `>` in terminal after invoke the `.py` file :

```
$~ python my_file.py > save_file.txt
```

Comment: I think OP wants the program to behave as if invoked as `python program.py | tee logfile`.

Comment: Create a method that does f.write and print and use search and replace to change the current method to this new one.