# Is there the redirect operator >> in Python 3?

Tags: bash, python-2.7, python-3.x

I did not know there was a *redirect* operator in Python 2, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906764/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-file-and-console-with-scripting) somebody is using it to redirect something to a file. I just knew that there is one in *Bash*. Is still there such a thing in Python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function in Python 3.x optionally accept `file` parameter, you can specify file object.

```
import sys

print(n, file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the shell redirection this way

```
python foo_bar.py > file
```

is still possible with python 3.x as this is not a feature of python itself but this is actually a feature of the shell interpreter in which the python command is run.