# Print output in file and terminal stdout python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, stdout

I've added the following line to a python file in order to output all `print` strings to a file:

`sys.stdout = open(logf, 'wb')`

This does what I wanted, but also stops all `print` strings from appearing in the terminal.  Is there a way to configure stdout to print to both destinations?  (I'm trying to avoid writing a function for each use of `print` because there are many and it's a lot to rewrite.  Also, I've perused several similar topics, but I haven't found a simple method.)

Comment: You could exclude that line, and simply do `python prog.py | tee filename`

Comment: why not use the logging module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: Is there a "print to terminal" specific statement or function?  E.G. if I have `print` going to stdout, can I specifically print some things to the terminal while that's the case?

Answer (score 0):

```
def fprint(output):
    print output
    with open("somefile.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write("{}\n".format(output))
```

This function would do it for you, use instead of print.

Comment: I saw this on SO from another question.  I was just hoping there was another way to do this directly, or a way to alter the behavior of stdout.

Comment: This one would work perfectly too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906764/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-file-and-console-with-scripting