# Dump curses window output to a file in python

Tags: python, ncurses, python-curses

I am trying to dump the output of curses window into a file without displaying it on stdout. Currently I am using addstr() function to print on stdout and at the end I am calling instr() function to dump the entire screen into a file. In certain cases, the ncurses does not work properly on xterm and hence I need to redirect the output to a file without actually printing it on stdout. I thought of using logger module but I lose color coding which addstr() provides. What is the best method to achieve this?

For example:

If I run the following command

```
$ python get_stats.py
```

it should display on stdout and when I run the command

```
$ python get_stats.py --dump-to-file
```

it should dump to a file without displaying on stdout.
Does addstr() takes additional parameters to determine whether the output should go to a file or stdout?

Answer (score 0):

No, `addstr` does not take additional parameters.  By default (using `initscr`, that is), curses writes to the standard output.  You could simply do

```
python get_stats.py >myfile
```

But for making a program option, you would have to tell Python (or curses) to write to the given file. Python's binding for ncurses does not include [`newterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html), which is the usual way of controlling the output stream.  But in Python, you can redirect the standard output as discussed in these questions:

- [Temporarily Redirect stdout/stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr)
- [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)
- [how to redirect stdout to file and console with scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906764/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-file-and-console-with-scripting)

Because curses saves a copy of the output stream locally, you must do the redirection *before* calling `initscr`.  Also, keep in mind that curses may use the *file descriptor* rather than the buffered output stream.

Comment: no problem (if you get stuck, posting the script here may get results)

Comment: now I am using generic print function which takes handle and the content to be displayed. If the handle is for file, it will be written to file else on ncurses window