# How to redirect python print to a file while running it inside a screen session

Tags: python, gnu-screen

I have a simple python script test.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("Hello")
```

I try to redirect the printing to a file, inside a screen session. The following things work:

Without screen:

```
python test.py > out.txt
```

With screen, step by step:

```
screen -S tmp
python test.py > out.txt
exit
```

However what I really need is not working (out.txt remains empty):

```
screen -Sdm tmp python test.py > out.txt
```

After reading a seemingly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered) I also tried:

```
screen -Sdm tmp stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 python test.py > out.txt
```

But it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However what I really need is not working (out.txt remains empty):
>
> ```
> screen -Sdm tmp python test.py > out.txt
> ```

That command works as follows:

- The shell launches the `screen` program with standard output redirected to `out.txt`
- In the `screen` session `python` is run without any output redirection. One might expect that the output of python should eventually be sent to `out.txt` anyway, because of the output redirection applied to its parent process. However, that doesn't happen since `screen` does its own management of output streams.

You can solve the problem by making the output redirection happen inside the `screen` session as follows:

```
screen -Sdm tmp bash -c "python test.py > out.txt"
```

This runs under `screen` the following command:

```
bash -c "python test.py > out.txt"
```

which stands for *start bash and execute inside it the command* `"python test.py > out.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of how you could redirect the output externally or how that screen command works, but if modifying that Python program is under your control, what about [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14906787/1712861)? You could write something like this at the very beginning of your program:

```
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, logfile):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(logfile, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)  # This might be optional for you
        self.log.write(message)  

    def flush(self):
        #this flush method is needed for python 3 compatibility.
        #this handles the flush command by doing nothing.
        #you might want to specify some extra behavior here.
        pass    

if len(sys.argv) > 1:  # Just in case no argument was passed to the program
    sys.stdout = Logger(sys.argv[1])
```

By doing this, you would not need to rewrite every print statement. You would then use your `screen` command without the `>` redirection, passing the file as a normal argument:

```
screen -Sdm tmp python test.py out.txt
```

Or perhaps you might require quotation marks for this to work:

```
screen -Sdm tmp python "test.py out.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using the file read/write ?
example:

```
file = open("path/to/file", "w")
file.write("Hello")
file.close
```

Comment: I want to apply this to an already written and large python program. Therefore I want to avoid rewriting every print statement if possible.

Answer (score -2):

How about just implementing some logging? Use [daiquiri](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daiquiri) the simplify it.