# How to both capture shell command output AND show it in terminal at realtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, stdout

I wrote a function, which runs external commands and captures their outputs, something like this

```
    proc = subprocess.run(command_line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if proc.returncode != 0:
```

Unfortunately, I don't see long commands output as they running. How to do this conditionally, for example, if loglevel is debug or higher?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking. Do you want to have a "debug mode" that prints the output on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, something like this. I want to control, either print output or not, but capture it always

Comment: Have you considered using `check_output()` instead of `run()`?

Comment: How can I turn printing on and off with `check_output()`?

Comment: output = check_output(...). The you can print it or not as you want

Comment: This will be possible only when command is finished, while I wish to print output during the way

Comment: Yes, this can work only after the command is executed till completion.

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/ddg#418899

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906764/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-both-file-and-console-with-scripting

Answer (score 0):

This code will print the command output as soon as it is received:

```py
import sys
import subprocess
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=shell)
except OSError as e:
    print('Error executing command', command, e)
    raise
for stdout_line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''):
    sys.stdout.write(stdout_line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
proc.stdout.close()
```