# conda force remove python broken the installation all

Tags: python, conda

I previously have the problem that in pdb debuging, when I type arrow keys, it generates `^[[D^[[A^[[B^[[C`, someone says I have to reinstall python and suggests to do

```
conda remove --force python
conda install python
```

but after the

```
conda remove --force python
```

then run `conda` only gives

```
-bash: /home/user/anaconda2/bin/conda: /home/user/anaconda2/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I should not follow the advice...can someone help me?

Comment: Conda runs on Python.  When you removed Python, you effectively removed Conda as well.  What system are you on?

Comment: Adding to James's comment, the better way reinstall python is to reinstall Anaconda itself or create a new environment. You can use this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda) as a reference.

Comment: @James, I'm using ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: @Nitred reinstalled Anaconda, can you suggest how to solve the pdb arrow key problem?

Comment: @K.Wanter Unfortunately I have no experience with `pdb`. Maybe you could give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140198/python-debugger-pdb-stopped-handlying-up-down-arrows-shows-a-instead) a try.