# How to make key binding for history search work in python repl in OSX?

Tags: python, macos

I was using the below pystartup script in linux to make history  and autocompletion on tab available in REPL Python. I have switched to OSX and I have modified the script such that tab completion works. But I am not able to figure out how to make the search work? Search couple of SO questions like 
[Python interactive mode history and arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483723/python-interactive-mode-history-and-arrow-keys)

But I don't want to uninstall the python version that comes with OSX as it may lead to some other dependency breakages.

My python version is 2.7.10

Script

```
import atexit
import os
import readline
import rlcompleter

historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.pyhistory")

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
    import readline
    readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
   readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")
else:
   readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

readline.set_history_length(1000)
atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history)
del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath
```

Comment: The script works with the system python on High Sierra 10.13.4; I can also confirm it is built with readline support: `$ python -c "import readline; print(readline.__file__)"` returns `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so`, `$ python -c "import readline; print(readline.__file__)" | xargs otool -L` shows that it is linked against `libedit` and `libncurses`. What MacOS version do you have?

Comment: Also, where do you put the script - is it the correct path? Mine is `$ python -c "import site; print(site.getusersitepackages())" | xargs -I {} ls {}/sitecustomize.py`, which returns `/Users/hoefling/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sitecustomize.py` on my machine.

Comment: BTW, you won't be able to uninstall system python completely anyway, at least not without turning SIP off, so I wouldn't care about that.

Comment: I have high sierra.

Comment: After the answer given by Tarun, I was able to get the history search. The problem was with virtualenv which was pointing to system python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall Mac OSX python. You should just install new python that can co-exist with system python.

Use below to install Python 2.7.X

```
brew install python@2
```

Use below to install Python 3.6.X

```
brew install python
```

If you don't have brew then setup the same following steps mentioned on

https://brew.sh

Once you do that it will automatically work

[image: Readline default]