# Rpdb debugging in Docker - can't use arrows or ssh

Tags: docker, python-3.7, remote-debugging, pdb

I have a Django-Server inside a Docker and would like to be able to do remote-debug my scripts.
The arrow-keys just won't work. I'm getting

```
(Pdb) ^[[A
```

instead of something useful.
I'm just using a plain terminal on Ubuntu. No IDE or anything fancy.

As stated [here](https://medium.com/@vladyslav.krylasov/how-to-use-pdb-inside-a-docker-container-eeb230de4d11) I rewrote my docker-compose and it works with this line just fine:

```
__import__("remote_pdb").set_trace(host='0.0.0.0', port=4444)
```

With telnet I'm able to use *most* features of the pdb: `telnet 0.0.0.0 4444`
What's not working are the arrow-keys. Someone had that problem as well and I installed [readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140198/python-debugger-pdb-stopped-handlying-up-down-arrows-shows-a-instead) as this guy had the same problem: [Python interactive mode history and arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483723/python-interactive-mode-history-and-arrow-keys)

```
dnf install ncurses-devel
pip3 install readline
```

No changes. (Installation works. I can import `readline`).
I'm assuming the issue might come from the telnet. So I'm thinking of switching to [ssh -t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/893175/2516892).

But now I'm supposed to log in:

```
ssh -t 0.0.0.0 -P 4444
qohelet@0.0.0.0's password:
```

There is no password. It's just a Docker. Also I wouldn't know the username.

I keep searching dand 2017 just called. I'm supposed to user [gnureadline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210086/2516892). No difference:

```
(Pdb) import gnureadline
(Pdb) ^[[A
```

I'm stuck now.

Comment: @user13182570 - Trying to debug as much as I can in Unit-Tests. It's a more proper way I assume. So my views.py is as compact as possible. All the functionality is moved to other classes